# How will i resolve Dependency of interfaces which is on 3rd or 4rth layer

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, software-design, n-tier-architecture

I am creating an architecture in `Dotnet Core 3.1`.

I have created Layers

API

-> Controller

-> Service Interface. (This will be used by Controller Layer)

-> Service Implementation

-> Data Interface. (This will be used by Service Implementation Layer as a dependency)

-> Data Implementation

I do not want to expose my Data Implementation to the Controller layer but it has to use in the constructor of the Service Implementation Layer.

The question is:

How to resolve the Data Implementation Classes?

And how to register these classes in IServiceCollection?

Comment: Show some code to provide a better example of what you are referring.

Comment: As Nksoi said, please provide code samples to help illustrate your current design. Can't recommend a solution without knowing what dependencies each layer is currently taking on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by:

1. Defining Separate Projects for each Layer.
2. Setting the Dependencies among Layers as much as you need.
3. Model mapping should be in `Service Layer` rather than in Controller layer (Normally should be in Controller Layer but in your scenario is not applicable).
4. Install `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` NuGet in your `Service Layer`
5. Define Extension Method for `DependencyInjection` in `Service Layer`.
6. Call the extension method in `Startup.cs`

I prepared an example explaining the answer.

The Example:

*The Solution Skeleton with Dependencies:*
[image: Solution Skeleton and Project Dependencies]

*Example Products Endpoint interfaces and classes distribution over solution*
[image: Example endpoint interfaces and classes distribution]

*Dependency Injection for the endpoint services*
[image: Dependency Injection for the endpoint services]

Controller Class Code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using TestProj.AppServices.Interfaces;

namespace TestProj.Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ProductsController> _logger;
        private readonly IProductService _service;

        public ProductsController(ILogger<ProductsController> logger,
                                  IProductService service)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _service = service;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id=1}")] //Set default value for example only, it should be [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            return Ok(_service.GetById(id));
        }
    }
}
```

ProductService

```
    using TestProj.AppServices.Interfaces;
    using TestProj.AppServices.Models;
    using TestProj.Data.Interfaces;
    
    namespace TestProj.AppServices.AppServices
    {
        public class ProductService : IProductService
        {
            private readonly IProductRepository _repository;
    
            public ProductService(IProductRepository repository)
            {
                _repository = repository;
            }
            public Product GetById(int id)
            {
                //Subject code here
    
                //Dummy code:
                var productFromDataLayer = _repository.GetById(id);
    
                //Mapping (You can use AutoMapper NuGet)
                var product = new Product
                {
                    Id = productFromDataLayer.Id,
                    Name = productFromDataLayer.Name
                };
    
                return product;
            }
        }
    }
```

IProductService

```
using TestProj.AppServices.Models;

namespace TestProj.AppServices.Interfaces
{
    public interface IProductService
    {
        Product GetById(int id);
    }
}
```

Product Service Layer Model

```
namespace TestProj.AppServices.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ProductRepository

```
using TestProj.Data.Interfaces;
using TestProj.Data.Model;

namespace TestProj.Data.Data
{
    public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        public Product GetById(int id)
        {
            //Subject code here

            //Dummy code:
            var product = new Product
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Product 1"
            };

            return product;
        }
    }
}
```

IProductRepository

```
using TestProj.Data.Model;

namespace TestProj.Data.Interfaces
{
    public interface IProductRepository
    {
        Product GetById(int id);
    }
}
```

Data Layer Product Model (Entity)

```
namespace TestProj.Data.Model
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Dependency Injection Extension Class

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using TestProj.AppServices.AppServices;
using TestProj.AppServices.Interfaces;
using TestProj.Data.Data;
using TestProj.Data.Interfaces;

namespace TestProj.AppServices.Others
{
    public static class DependencyInjection
    {
        public static void AddProjectServicesAndRepositoresDependencyInjection(this IServiceCollection services)
        {

            //Services
            services.AddTransient<IProductService, ProductService>();

            //Data
            services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
        }
    }
}
```

Startup class

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using TestProj.AppServices.Others;

namespace TestProj.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddProjectServicesAndRepositoresDependencyInjection();

            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I have uploaded the source code of the example to GitHub https://github.com/ualehosaini/LayeredArchitecturePreparedToAnswerForAStackOverflowQuestion . You can use it for your projects, you can define/add whatever component you need.

Comment: Thank you sir. You got the correct scenario for my problem. You are suggesting to create new project to manage dependency for all layers?

Comment: No worries :),  Yes, you can imagine the projects as a firewall and defined dependencies as what you allow only. Follow the steps of the sample project.